# Regex replace only double hyphens inside quotations

Tags: php, regex

I have a document that's full of quotes, so like: `"this is a quote"`. Some of those quotes have subclauses in two hyphens like: `"this quote - this one right here - has em dashes"`, and some just have one hyphen like: `"this quote has just one thing - a hyphen"`.

I'm trying to have some `regex` that matches all of the quotes with two hyphens, but not match any quotes with zero or one hyphen, and not match any of the text outside of the quotes. Also I should mention that there are some sentences with one or more hyphens that lie outside of quotes, I need to ignore them as well and not have them interfere with my matches in quotes. I want to change the properly matched quotes' double hyphens to proper em dash characters.

I've tried using `lookaheads` and negated characters, but can't seem to figure this one out.

Is this something `regex` can do, or do I need to come up with some kind of other approach (like splitting all of the text into an array and stepping through it, making my changes and then recombining it all at the end)? I can do that instead it just seems like a silly waste of time if there's a one-line regex statement that will do what I want.

Comment: post the regex that you have tried

Comment: http://regexr.com/3a34k

Comment: Tha's like one I tried, but it fails if there are hyphens outside of the quotes. (make a non-quoted sentence in your example into a double hyphen sentence, you'll see).

I've actually tried probably dozens of permutations over the last few days, I'm sorry I don't have a list of them all!

Comment: I'm sorry, but have you tried it? http://regexr.com/3a34t
It doesnt fail when there are -'s outside the quotes..

Comment: add this string to the end of your example text:

Here is a sentence that's not a quote - but now - it has two hypehns anyways. "and here is another quote".

And see what I mean.

Comment: The example didn't work as posted, but I was able to modify it to get it to do what I need, thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you have solved your problem, add it as an answer or accept an answer below. This lets others know that this question has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `\b` word boundary at the beginning of the quote, and check that the last character inside the quote is either a letter or number or some kind of punctuation.

```
("\b[^-"]*-[^-"]*-[^-"]*[\w.!?]")
```

Answer (score 0):

`"(?:[^-"]*-){2}[^-"]*"` is about the best you can get with only regex, but it doesn't work if there are two hyphens outside of quotes. Splitting the text into an array is probably the best way to do what you want to.